# tab-delimited string to XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, csv, splfileobject

I'm trying to write the tab-delimited content of a variable to XML like this:

```
$tsvData = str_getcsv($input, "\t");
foreach($tsvData as $line => $row) {
    if($line > 0) {
        $xmlWriter->writeElement('NAME', $row[0]);
        $xmlWriter->writeElement('CAKE', $row[1]);
        $xmlWriter->writeElement('BODYPART', $row[2]);
    }
}
```

But it's only writing one character per XML tag instead of everything between each tab. When I use SplFileObject, geting the same tsv data but from a file, it works.  What am I doing wrong with the str_getcsv function?

Thanks

Comment: What is the `var_dump($line)` and the `var_dump($tsvData)`?

Comment: var_dump for $tsvData is correct, but $line gives me a single array of ints. drrcknlsn explained it below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `str_getcsv()` function returns a 1-dimensional array, but you're treating it like it's returning a 2-dimensional array.

**Edit:**

To clarify, `str_getcsv()` has no concept of "lines".  Instead of doing this:

```
$tsvData = str_getcsv($input, "\t");
```

Thinking that you'll get an array of lines, each one containing an array of columns, you have to do something like this:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $input);
$tsvData = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $tsvData[] = str_getcsv($line, "\t");
}
// now $tsvData is a 2-dimensional array of lines/columns like you were wanting
```

Comment: Ah, yes. I was thinking it worked like SplFileObject, but for data already held in the page. Thanks for your help! That works great.